# Align image, icon and name in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**home.html**

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            </ul>
            <span class="navbar-text" s>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" class="bellicon" style=" border-right: 1px solid #d0c4c4;" >
                        <span class="bellprite bellie"></span>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item active" class="navv" >
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" style="display:inline; margin-left: 20px;">

                           <li >

                               <span> <img class="profile-face"  src="./images/profile.jpg">
                                <span> Kishore Sagande </span>
                                <span class="downprite downie"></span>


                          </li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
```

[image: Expecting Structure]
[image: Current structure]

This is the bootstrap 4 navigation bar which is right aligned. How to align the given items in a proper structure?

Comment: Found some html errors. fix that first

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.

```css
.navbar .divider-vertical {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 9px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.btn-transparent {
  background: transparent;
}

.avatar {
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md align-self-center">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/65.jpg" class="avatar rounded-circle" alt="Cinque Terre">
            Wilma Roth
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

3 possible things to do:

- give padding-top & padding-bottom for the right container
- vertical-align:middle for the right aligned element
- set line-height for both of the inner-element

ps: use "!important" for the css which is overriding bootstrap css